# How can I convert some categories to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a WordPress install that has a ton of categories. I want to convert some of these categories into a custom taxonomy. For example, I have:

Categories:

- Category A

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
- Category B

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
- Category C

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2

And I would like to make Category C and all of its subcategories into a completely separate custom taxonomy. Is there a way that I can make this conversion, while keeping the relationships between Category C and existing posts intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create whatever new taxonomies you want to by adding register_taxonomy() function in functions.php

After that you can simply assign all the posts related to Category C to that custom taxonomy using [Convert Post types plugin](http://stephanieleary.com/code/wordpress/convert-post-types/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to change post types, as they are all WordPress' native posts. And some posts may be categorized in Category A and Category C. Do you happen to know is this plugin will allow for that functionality? I will check it out later today.

Comment: You can use this plugin for converting posts from a category or custom taxonomy to another category or custom taxonomy on bulk.

Comment: I have the plugin installed, but I can't seem to find how to change categories to custom taxonomy. Under "Convert From" and "Convert To" I only see Post, Page, and Attachment. I don't see Category or Taxonomy as options.

Comment: Since, you are not converting posts from post/page to custom post type, so you can select "Convert From post" and "Convert to post" options and then you can select the category from which post needed to be converted from "Limit Post Category" drop down. After that you can assign custom taxonomy to it from the taxonomy listing appearing at the bottom. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks for all of your help. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This did the trick -- Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: It does seem to have some issues with maintaining hierarchy of terms, but I will continue to see if there is a way to get this resolved.

Comment: Glad it works for you. What are the issues that you are facing with maintaining hierarchy?

Comment: I don't think my formatting will carry over correctly in the comments, but I posted on the support forum in the plugin directory. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-convert-post-types-possible-to-maintain-hierarchy-when-changing-categories-to-custom-taxonomy I select convert from post to post limit posts to Category C and then I select Category C under Assign custom taxonomy terms. The conversion works, but it doesn't transfer the subcategories. If I select Category C AND Subcategory 1 then it applies the subcategory correctly, but it does not select apply Category C to the posts.

Comment: What would be great would be to also answer this question with a piece of PHP code...